# Error "function (constructor) already has a body" For derived classes even after including header guards

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am trying to create derived classes based on one class. Whenever I go to compile, it gives me an error saying that my constructor functions already have bodies. Some googling suggested  that including header guards would correct this, but that doesn't seem to help either. Here is the related code

ProductionWorker.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _PRODUCTIONWORKER_H_
#define _PRODUCTIONWORKER_H_

#include "Employee.h"

...

public:
    ProductionWorker():Employee(){}
    ProductionWorker(string n, string i, double s, int shift, int h, double p) :Employee(n, i, s){}

...

#endif
```

ProductionWorker.cpp

```
#include "ProductionWorker.h"

ProductionWorker::ProductionWorker() : Employee() {
    shift = 0;
    hours = 0;
    payRate = 0;
}

ProductionWorker::ProductionWorker(string n, string i, double s, int shft, int h, double p) :Employee(n, i, s)
{
    shift = shft;
    hours = h;
    payRate = p;
}
```

Comment: E.g. What do you think `ProductionWorker():Employee(){}` is doing? It isn't just declaring the existence of a constructor. Likewise for the subsequent constructor.

Comment: Before you close as typo, what would be the corrected declaration? Simply removing the {}  gives me a compiler error "Expected {"

Comment: `ProductionWorker();` . The second one I leave to you to trim.

Comment: I retracted my close vote, since I didn't realize at first that the initializer lists are also erroneously there. This to me doesn't look like a typo anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The final answer ended up being two errors on my part. The first was the inclusion of "{}" rather than ";". What I had initially was an inline definition instead of a declaration. I had also included the base class in my declaration as if I was making a definition. The corrected code looks like this

ProductionWorker.h

```
public:
    ProductionWorker();
    ProductionWorker(string n, string i, double s, int shift, int h, double p);
```

I can see that simpler questions such as this one are not embraced on Stack Overflow. Would someone point me to a forum that welcomes more "beginner" questions?